# Cannot insert comments on a table in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I have a document with a table. I can insert comments (under the Review tab) anywhere, but for some reason I am not allowed to add comments inside the table (even though the text inside the table is perfectly editable). The option becomes greyed out as soon as I select the table.

Is this disallowed in Word? How can I add comments referring to a table or elements of the table?

I'm using Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue with Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010. I created a new blank document, created a 2x2 table, typed some text into the table, and was able to add a comment for each cell. Can you describe more about your document? Maybe the table is "Protected". Can you reproduce the behavior with a new blank document?

Comment: I too am unable to reproduce the issue in Word 2010 - I can add comments to individual table cells or the entire table without any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am reading your question correctly, you need to change the way Word views the comments to be inline. Here is how to do it; `Review Ribbon > Tracking > Show Markup > Balloons` select `Show All Revisions Inline`.

[image]